# react-native - how to center align text in picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react native app I display 4 pickers next to each other.

on ios, I display the pickers and everything works really well

[image]

but on android, the text from some reason is aligned to the left[image]

here is my code

```
<View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            flex: 1,
            height: "20%",
            maxHeight: "20%",
            marginTop: "5%",
            marginBottom: "5%",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Picker
            style={{
              ...styles.picker,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 6,
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 6,
            }}
            itemStyle={styles.pickerItemStyle}
            mode="dropdown"
          >
            <Picker.Item
              label="BR"
              value="BR"
              color={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "#fff" : "black"}
            />
            <Picker.Item
              label="PS"
              value="PS"
              color={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "#fff" : "black"}
            />
          </Picker>
          <Picker
            mode="dropdown"
            style={styles.picker}
            itemStyle={styles.pickerItemStyle}
          >
            <Picker.Item
              label="D"
              value="D"
              color={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "#fff" : "black"}
            />
            <Picker.Item
              label="E"
              value="E"
              color={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "#fff" : "black"}
            />
          </Picker>
          <Picker
            mode="dropdown"
            style={styles.picker}
            itemStyle={styles.pickerItemStyle}
          >
            <Picker.Item
              label="IF"
              value="IF"
              color={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "#fff" : "black"}
            />
            <Picker.Item
              label="VVS1"
              value="VVS1"
              color={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "#fff" : "black"}
            />
          </Picker>
          <Picker
            mode="dropdown"
            style={styles.picker}
            itemStyle={styles.pickerItemStyle}
          >
            <Picker.Item
              label="-32%"
              value="-32%"
              color={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "#fff" : "black"}
            />
            <Picker.Item
              label="-33%"
              value="-33%"
              color={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "#fff" : "black"}
            />
          </Picker>
        </View>

  picker: {
    // flex: 0.5,
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 12,
    backgroundColor: "#030E21",
    marginTop: "5%",
    width: "25%",
  },
  pickerItemStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    maxHeight: "100%",
    textAlign: "center",
    width: "100%",
  },
```

I am using expo and I don't want to eject only for this alignment

anyone knows how it can be don't with styling ?

Comment: i tried it and it doesnt work

Comment: @Harel: If that doesn't work, can you add white borders to your picker elements?  Because you are using black borders and a black background, it's really impossible to see where these elements are or should be, especially without a working demo.

Comment: i tried to put borders but this does not seem to work on android, in ios I am able to show border but on android not

Comment: @Harel It seems that the `text-align` does also work on the inner child elements as well and not just on the TextNode (the text that is a direct child to the element). Sorry for the inconveniance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set the elements to have `alignItems:center`, this seems to only control the, "the `align-self` value on all direct children as a group," according to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).  In the MDN example, the text is *always centered*, no matter how `alignItems` is set.

Have you tried adding this to your `style` definition?

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: @Harel: Thanks, I added a comment up above, you'll need to make some sort of working demo or add white borders around your elements, and then take another screenshot.  That's the only way I'll be able to see what's happening.  At least then I'll know it's not a cache problem.  **NOTE**: Without `text-align` being set, there's no reason for the text to align at all.